# How to debug installation of self-made package

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, productbuild

I am currently creating a [macOS package for IRAF](https://github.com/olebole/iraf-mac-build). On some systems, I get the error message (when using the command line **installer**; similar message when installing though clicking on the package)

```
$ sudo installer -pkg iraf-x86_64.pkg -target / -verboseR
installer: Package name is Community IRAF 2.17.1 (r1)
installer: Installing at base path /
installer:PHASE:Preparing for installation…
installer: The install failed. (The Installer can’t locate the data it needs to install the software. Check your install media or internet connection and try again, or contact the software manufacturer for assistance. )
```

How can one debug this, i.e. find out which data is missing? Earlier builds succeeded, and I have no idea what change could cause this.